# AP CS Lab - Elevens: Ranks of playing cards?

Tags: java, arrays

For AP CS, there is a lab in which you make a card game called elevens. The labs give you starter code and you have to work off of it to make a finished product for each activity. In this activity they are asking that arrays are used to make up a deck constructor, using an array for point values, suit, and "rank". What would this rank array contain?

Here are the instruction: http://media.collegeboard.com/digitalServices/pdf/ap/elevens-lab-student-guide.pdf

```
public Deck(String[] ranks , String[] suits, int[] values) {
        ranks = new String[] {/*What goes here?*/};
        suits = new String[] {"Clubs","Diamonds","Hearts","Spades"};
        values = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,};


    }
```

Comment: This isn't programming related per se, but *rank* refers to A, 2 through 9, J, Q, K.  The point value is a quantity that is assigned depending on the rules of the game.  (This is evident once you read some of the examples in the instructions.)

Comment: If you are a teacher, I suggest posting this on the College Board's list. You should also have the completed working project.

Comment: _rank_ refers to A, 2 through 10, J, Q, K.  (Not 1 through 9.)  (Not 2 through 9 either.)  The order depends on the game.  In many games the A (ace) is the highest card, and the rest of the cards are in the order I listed; in some of them the ace is lowest.

Comment: Thanks for the information! And also @Thorn I'm a student so I don't have access to completed code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's the point of passing in code when you are overriding them?
e.g. either have

```
public Deck() {
 this.ranks = new String[] {"Ace", "King" .... };
}
```

Otherwise go for

```
public Deck(String[] ranks .....) {
   this.ranks = ranks;
    ...... 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Just started the project and was too focused on figuring out what it was asking for to realize my error